# No apaga las mediciones del sensor cuando aprieto el boton

Tags: python-3.x

Necesitó que no se vea la salida impresa en la consola de la aplicación Thonny, cuando presiono el botón del microcontrolador y cuando lo dejé de oprimir vuelva a aparecer la impresión en consola, el cogido que he desarrollado en micropython es el siguiente:

```
from machine import Pin
import _thread
import time

LED = 2
BUTTON=0
# Lock to avoid race condition when accessing the flag
myLock = _thread.allocate_lock()

# Flag to control threads execution
flag = True
boton = Pin(BUTTON, Pin.IN)
# Function to simulate sensor measurements
def sensor_measurement():
    while True:
        if flag:
            mediciones = "Medición del sensor:"
            print("Medición del sensor:", mediciones)
            print(boton.value())
            time.sleep(1)

# Function to read user button and control sensor measurement printing
def control_sensor_printing():
   
    global flag
    while True:
        user_input = input("Press Enter to start/stop sensor measurement printing: ")
        if boton.value() == 0:
            myLock.acquire()
            flag = not flag  # Toggle the flag
            mediciones(not mediciones)
            myLock.release()

# Start Thread1 for sensor measurements
_thread.start_new_thread(sensor_measurement, ())

# Start Thread2 for controlling sensor measurement printing
_thread.start_new_thread(control_sensor_printing, ())

# Main thread is an endless loop
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Te sugiero que le eches un vistazo a esto: [class threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Esta es la corrección al cogido:

    from machine import Pin
    import _thread
    #This file is executed on every boot (including wake-boot from deepsleep)
    # import esp
    # esp.osdebug(None)
    # import webrepl
    # webrepl.start()

    import time
    from machine import ADC
    from machine import deepsleep

    BUTTON=0
    # Lock to avoid race condition when accessing the flag
    myLock = _thread.allocate_lock()

    # Flag to control threads execution
    flag = True
    boton = Pin(BUTTON, Pin.IN)
    # Function to simulate sensor measurements
    def sensor_measurement():
        cuenta=0
        while True:
            if flag:
                pin = Pin(34)
                adc=ADC(pin)
                mediciones = adc.read()
                print("Medición del sensor:", mediciones)
                print(cuenta)
                cuenta=cuenta+1
            time.sleep(1)

    # Function to read user button and control sensor measurement printing
    def control_sensor_printing():

        global flag
        status=0
        while True:
            #user_input = input("Press Enter to start/stop sensor measurement printing: ")
            if status==0:
                if boton.value() == 0:
                    status=1
    
            else:
                if boton.value() == 1:
                    status=0
        
                    myLock.acquire()
                    flag = not flag  # Toggle the flag
                    myLock.release()
            
            time.sleep(0.01)

    # Start Thread1 for sensor measurements
    _thread.start_new_thread(sensor_measurement, ())

    # Start Thread2 for controlling sensor measurement printing
    _thread.start_new_thread(control_sensor_printing, ())

    # Main thread is an endless loop
    while True:
        pass
    print('Im awake, but Im going to sleep')
    #sleep for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

    if button.value()==0:
        deepsleep(1000)
```

Comment: ¿Es esto una respuesta o una edición a tu pregunta? Si es lo primero, leé [answer] y describí qué fue lo que modificaste. Si es lo segundo, pulsá en editar en tu pregunta y eliminá esta _no respuesta_. Y por cierto, es la segunda vez que tenés un error de tipeo al escribir _código_...